# How to set timeout value in NpgsqlConnection?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-5, npgsql

From Documentation:
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html
[image: Docs]

Connection string:`"...;Timeout=1200"`;

Code:

```
public IDbConnection Connection
{
    get
    {
        return new NpgsqlConnection() { ConnectionString = this.config.GetConnectionString("PostgresConn") };
    }
}
```

...

```
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
    {                
        return dbConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>(query, new { OP = op }) > 0;
    }
```

Error message:

> Couldn't set timeout (Parameter 'timeout')

Comment: May be ConnectionTimeout?

Comment: If the keyword was wrong you'd probably get an error saying that. Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just the `Message` property. The full text contains any inner exceptions that may explain what's wrong.

Comment: In fact, as the source code shows, `1200` is out of range. `Timeout` is the connection timeout. A connection timeout of 20 minutes is useless. It means the network connection failed or the server has issues. You should retry the connection, not wait forever. If the server failed to respond in 1 minute, it probably can't respond at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a more explicit error message specifying the timeout must be less than 1024

> System.ArgumentException: Couldn't set timeout (Parameter 'timeout')
> ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Timeout must be between 0 and 1024 (Parameter 'value')

and this is confirmed in the code [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/fa31b5989a433a75f9ab06b51dafd90e21344b14/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnection.cs#L119) and [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/096d4ca61c1484116b03ed1b3b04355374ef6d81/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs#L826):

Comment: You should probably explain that `Timeout` is the connection, not the command timeout. Waiting for 20 minutes for a connection is meaningless. Even the maximum value, 1024, isn't realistic.